Rivatuner (RTSS) xmax correction formula is no longer available
Not sure why, but RTSS stopped using the xmax formula, that used to work perfectly fine before.
formula xmax is the function to store/show the higher value reached by that sensor/stat.
now is being showed as red text, and can't save the change.
I wonder if anyone knows what changed?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

These are the new functions implemented in the 7.3.6 version
https://www.guru3d.com/download/rtss-rivatuner-statistics-server-download/
New statmin, statavg, statmax and statstd 


Improved data source statistics access functionality. Previously you could access each data source's statistics via local xmin/xavg/xmax/xswa variables specified inside the source’s correction formulas only and such variables couldn't be accessed from other data sources. Such local statistics variables are deprecated since this version, now you can use more robust functions for accessing each data source's statistics:

New statmin, statavg, statmax and statstd functions can be used to get global min/avg/max/std statistics for each data source and you can
access it from other sources, e.g. you may use statavg("CPU power") +
statavg("GPU1 power")) to calculate average CPU+GPU power consumption.
Global statistics is collected during whole OverlayEditor's runtime
session for synchronically polled sources only, for frametime and
PresentMon's data sources it reflects the last 1024 samples only




New swmin, swavg, swmax and swstd functions can be used to get sliding window based min/avg/max/std statistics for each data source, for example you may use swavg("CPU power", 8) to smooth CPU power consumption graph by calculating average CPU power with sliding window by 8 last sampled CPU power values. Maximum sliding window size is limited by each data source's ring buffer size, it is 512 samples for the most of OverlayEditor's data sources and 1024 for internal frametime and PresentMon's data sources. You may specify sliding window size as 0 to use whole ring buffer
New percentile and percentilei functions can be used to calculate classic (linear) and integral percentiles on ring buffer contents, so you can use it to calculate 1%/0.1% low framerates on PresentMon's data or add you own percentile based metrics. New ovl demonstrates new functions usage to display 1%/0.1% low framerates



The way to use these functions is:
statmax(x)

or
statmax(y)


Sry for noobing, i have tried to search on my own but can not seem to find the answer. I still got red text after switching to the new formulas/words. Any help would really be appreciated.
RTSS picture

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

You need to install the latest version 7.3.6, and use the axis with statmax(x)

Thank you and sry for putting the question in the wrong place. That wasnt my intention. Im apparantly learning the hard way. Should i just delete what i wrote?
